# Calling overridden function and using overloaded variable from base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding, overloading

I have two base classes and derivered versions that overload / override certain parts like this:

```
class base
{
public:
    int X = 1;
};

class deriv : public base
{
public:
    int X = 2;
};

class A
{
public:
    base K;
    virtual void doSmth()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        smthElse();
    }

    virtual void smthElse()
    {
        std::cout << K.X << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    deriv K;
    void doSmth()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
        smthElse();
    }
};
```

the application looks like this

```
int main()
{
    A instanceA;
    B instanceB;

    instanceA.doSmth();
    instanceB.doSmth();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output therefore is X=1 for both instances `A` and `B`. I was wondering why that is.
`A` uses `base` (X=1) and `B` uses `deriv` (X=2). `deriv` overloads `X` and `B` overloads `K`. Is this because the function `smthElse()` is only defined in `A`, thus `A` can't know about the existance of the overloaded variable `K`?

If so, is there a way for the function `smthElse()` to use the overloaded variable `K`?
I found the `using` keyword but also adding a `using A::smthElse;` in `B` won't change the behaviour of `X` not being printed as 2. The only way I can achieve this is by copying the function `smthElse()` from `A` and insert it into `B`.
Is there a different way to achieve what I'm looking for? Since it seems like an overkill to copy'n'paste the same function into `B` just to use an overridden variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While you can have polymorphic member function (using the `virtual` keyword), you can't have the same for member variables. Each class have its own *separate* member variable `K`, the one in `B` totally unrelated to the one in `A`.

Comment: Same apply to `derived::base::X` and `derived::X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceB` has two variables named `K`, `A::K` and `B::K`. However, the base class, `A`, only knows about one `K`, `A::K`.

That explains the output.

> If so, is there a way for the function `smthElse()` to use the overloaded variable K?

Yes, you can do that by adding a `virtual` function in `A` that returns a reference to `base` and adding a virtual function in `base` that returns a reference to `i`.

```
class base
{
public:
    int& getX( return X;}
private: 
    int X = 1;
};

class deriv : public base
{
public:
    int& getX( return X;}
private: 
    int X = 2;
};

class A
{
public:
    base& getK() { return K; }
    virtual void doSmth()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        smthElse();
    }

    virtual void smthElse()
    {
        std::cout << getK().getX() << std::endl;
        //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use the virtual functions
    }
public:
    base K;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    deriv& getK(){ return K; }
    void doSmth()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
        smthElse();
    }
public:
    base K;
};
```

**PS** I hope this is just curiosity and you don't write production code with such style. You will end up confusing yourself and anybody who tries to understand your code.

Comment: You might also avoid to have 2 `X`.

Comment: Nice answer, I'm happy to see we independently thought of the same solution.

Comment: @YSC, thanks. I noticed that you stopped at only virtual function when two are needed to get the behavior that the OP wants.

Comment: I prefered to simplify the example to let the reader focus on the proposed solution: a virtual getter for `K`.

Comment: Thanks for both your answers. And yes, this was just out of curiousity and not for productive code!

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
virtual void smthElse()
{
    std::cout << K.X << std::endl;
}
```

- `smthElse` is `virtual`
- `K` is not (a member variable could not be `virtual`: it has no meaning for an attribute).

In other terms, it means that `B::smthElse` will ovevrride `A::smthElse` but **`B::K` and `A::K` are two *distinct, unrelated and independent* variables.**

When `smthElse` is called in the context of a `B`, `K` still means `A::K`.

As a solution, you might create a virtual accessor to `K`s:

```
class base { ...};
class deriv{ ...};

class A
{
    base K;
public:
    virtual const base& theK() { return K; }
    virtual void smthElse() { std::cout << theK().X << "\n"; }
};

class B : public A
{
    deriv K;
public:
    virtual const base& theK() { return K; }
};
```

When `B{}.smthElse()` is called, it will call `B::theK()` which will return `B::K` (a `deriv instance`).

Comment: You know the saying that (almost) everything can be resolved ba adding a layer of abstraction?